# Unable to authorise an ORG in VS Code

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

Getting an error as below when trying to authorise an org.

In VS Code -
Error (1): Invalid client credentials. Verify the OAuth client secret and ID. Error authenticating with auth code due to: retry your request.

In Browser -
Error authenticating with auth code due to: retry your request.